# PHPMyAdmin Windows XAMPP Missing MySQL Extension Issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I've tried install Apache, PHP, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin manually and got the error. Then tried XAMPP and still got the error this error with PHPMyAdmin:

```
The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

I'm clueless of what the issue is. I've tried solutions on the web and none worked so far. This is a new Windows installation and I installed XAMPP on C:.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fairly simple fix.  Find your PHP.ini file, and in it there will be a list of extensions.  Look for the one that says mysql and take the `;` off the front of the line.

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

If you don't know where your PHP.ini file resides, you can put this code in a script to find out:

`phpinfo()`

Comment: This is odd. I opened the file and it was already uncommented and I just closed it and refreshed the page and it worked. weird. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5):

If after you've removed the semi-colons you STILL get this error. Your extension_dir value in php.ini may be the problem simply point the value to `extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"` (or wherever you store your php modules), restart your server and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your php.ini

```
extension= php_mysqli.dll
```

and stop and start apache and MySQL it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for the longest time on Xampp 7.4

I had already uncommented the line, however, what helped changing the

```
extension=php_mysql
```

to

```
 extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Comment: in my windows `extension=php_mysqli.dll` works

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR - 1. put extension=php_mysql.dll in php.ini > 2. REFRESH the error page!

Just encountered this problem right now;

what worked for me is using
"extension=php_mysql.dll";

you can find php.ini by clicking the config button in the xampp control panel for the apache module then selecting php.ini;

I also added xampp to path in system variables, idk if that specifically helped but its working now;

finally the most important step is to close the control panel to restart it and refresh the browser after opening mysql admin,because after applying every fix in this forum and clicking the admin for mysql it will still show the error screen but its already fixed you just need to refresh that error screen.