# The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I have looked through all of the forums that I could find relevant to this question and my problem yet nothing works. I have apache2.2 with php5, phpMyAdmin, and MySQL. I have uncommented the extension, I have checked my `phpinfo()` and mysqli does not come up. My config directory is where it should be and it still will not load.

Comment: Have you restarted apache? In order for changes in the php.ini to be taken into effect, apache needs to be restarted. Also, try php -m from the commandline.

Comment: What does Sql Server has to do with this?

Comment: Yeah I have restarted apache, and tried your php -m in the commandline. Nothing has worked yet.

Comment: I was facing the same issue when i update my php version from 5.6 to 7 and the solution i had to do is
try to check  my httpd-xampp config file.

Make sure the Php-Module conform with your current php version.

example here: IfModule php5_module

Based on my migration i was using php7, so edit all the php5_module tag in my config file to php7_module and restart the apache server.

Comment: As for the error message: "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. [See our ***documentation for more information***](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-receive-an-error-about-missing-mysqli-and-mysql-extensions)." - See also [Dude, where's my php.ini? (server config)](//stackoverflow.com/q/8684609) and restart PHP-FPM and/or webserver procceses after editing the right one.

Answer (score 25):

1. Find out [which php.ini is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini).
2. In file php.ini this line:

   ```
   extension=mysqli
   ```
3. Replace by:

   ```
   extension="C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"
   ```
4. Restart apache

Comment: Ok, worked for me. But setting an absolute path as the value to extension_dir (i.e., extension_dir = "c:\php\ext") seems to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Replace
include_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR 
with 
include_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR"

Answer (score 15):

If your configuration files are okay but still having the same issue then install php7.x-mysql according to the version of the installed php.

For example in my case, I'm using php7.3 so I ran the following command to get it all set:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql

systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: And run after

systemctl reload apache2

Comment: sudo apt install php8.2-mysql && sudo systemctl reload apache2

Comment: @Moccine Thank you! This worked perfectly after everything else failed.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a while ago but I encountered this and followed the other answers here but to no avail, I found the solution via this question ([Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617288/phpmyadmin-windows-xampp-missing-mysql-extension-issue))

Essentially just needed to edit the php.ini file (mine was found at c:\xampp\php\php.ini) and uncomment these lines...

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

After restarting apache all was working as expected.

Answer (score 6):

- In your Xampp folder, open `php.ini` file inside the PHP folder i.e `xampp\php\php.ini` (with a text editor).
- Search for `extension=mysqli` (Ctrl+F), if there are two, look for the one that has been uncommented (without ";" behind)
- Change the mysqli with the correct path address i.e `extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll`.
- On your Xampp control panel, stop and start apache and MySQL

Comment: Also, make sure you have uncommented this ```;extension_dir = "ext"``` line, because until then your extensions won't be found by the apache. To uncomment this just remove the semicolon (;) from the beginning like this ```extension_dir = "ext"``` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql

> extension=mysqli.so (add this php.ini file)

> sudo service apache2 restart

Please use above commands to resolve mysqli-extension missing error

Answer (score 2):

This article can help you [Configuring PHP with MySQL for Apache 2 or IIS in Windows](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/php_mysql_win.html). Look at the section "Configure PHP and MySQL under Apache 2", point 3:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\extensions"      ; FOR PHP 4 ONLY 
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"             ; FOR PHP 5 ONLY
```

You must uncomment extension_dir param line and set it to absolute path to the PHP extensions directory.

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside in the php.ini file from

```
; On windows:
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

to

```
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

Then enable the extension if it was disabled by changing

```
;extension=mysqli
```

to

```
extension=mysqli
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy libmysql.dll from the PHP installation folder to the windows folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for hours and no one could help me. I did a
simple thing to solve this problem. (WINDOWS 10 x64)

Follow this:

1 - Go to your php_mysqli.dll path (in my case: C:/xampp/php/ext);

2 - Move the php_mysqli.dll to the previous folder (C:/xampp/php);

3 - Open php.ini and search the line: "extension: php_mysqli.dll";

4 - Change to the path where is your file: extension="C:\xampp\php\php_mysqli.dll";

5 - Restart your application (wampp, xampp, etc.) and start Apache Server;

The problem was the path ext/php_mysqli.dll, I've tried changing the line to extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll" but doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it. You can solve it too if you follow these steps:

1. you have to install PHP to **C:/php**
   or your current version locate it to this path and specify it as a system variable
2. then open xampp program and click config and open php.ini
   and uncomment the following lines:

   ```
   extension=pdo_mysql
   extension=pdo_mysql
   extension=openssl
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try to change PHP version

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

if it didn't work
change for example from PHP 5.6 => PHP 7.1

```
    $ sudo a2dismod php5.6
    $ sudo a2enmod php7.1  
    $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today and eventually I realize it was the comment on the line before the mysql dll's that was causing the problem.

This is what you should have in php.ini by default for PHP 5.5.16:

```
;extension=php_exif.dll       Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Besides removing the semi-colons, you also need to delete the line of comment that came after php_exif.dll. This leaves you with

```
extension=php_exif.dll      
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

This solves the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied my php_myslqli.dll file from ert folder back to php folder, and it worked for me after restarting my Apache and MySQL from the control Panel

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue of extension directory. You need to change php extension directory manually to work this.

**If you are using AMPP Server, do the following**

Goto settings -> PHP -> Configuration

in php7.3.ini Find, (Versions might change)

extension_dir = ""  ,  (Already having some path)

and change value to

extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\Ampps\php-7.3\ext"

**If you are using XAMP**

Goto XAMP Settings, Apache ->  PHP.ini

Find, extension_dir =  in php.ini, and set path of the php extension folder of your local machine. See the below example.

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" (*Check your path properly*)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar issue after full installation of Debian 10.

**Commandline:**
`php -v` show I am using `php7.4` but print `phpinfo()` gives me `php7.3`

**Solution: Disable php7.3 Enable php7.4**

```
   $ a2dismod php7.3
    
   $ a2enmod php7.4
    
   $ update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
   $ update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
   $ update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
   $ update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
   $ update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
include_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR
```

with following

```
include_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

i.e Add commas , i checked apache error logs it was showing syntax error so checked whole file for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed my problem is: open `php.ini` then add this `extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Answer (score 0):

## for linux users

For me it was a weird behavior:
i went to phpmyadmin directory (for me `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`) and inside `index.php` file entered `phpinfo();`, then refreshed phpmyadmin web page;

surprisingly phpmyadmin was using different php version than what set on system. event `update-alternatives --config php` doesn't change situation;

so i just disabled all other php version using directly `a2dismod php8.1` (and whatever version you have) command and then enabled a version via `a2enmod` command.

hope help someone;