# Error in phpmyadmin - `mysqli extension is missing`

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

I`ve just installed LAMP stack (also tried with nginx) and after installing the phpmyadmin and trying to access 'localhost/phpmyadmin', I receive this message:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration
```

I already have tried the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work) and also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646655/the-mysqli-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration/16621413).

I tried to install on Ubuntu 18.04 'php7.2-mysql' (php 7.2 is my current version of php) and 'php7.2-mysqli' redirects to 'php7.2-mysql' and both of them are already installed at its newest version.

In the phpmyadmin documentation, here's what it is saying about the missing extension:

> 1.20 I receive an error about missing mysqli and mysql extensions.
>
> To connect to a MySQL server, PHP needs a set of MySQL functions called >“MySQL extension”. This extension may be part of the PHP distribution >(compiled-in), otherwise it needs to be loaded dynamically. Its name is >probably mysqli.so or php_mysqli.dll. phpMyAdmin tried to load the >extension but failed. Usually, the problem is solved by installing a >software package called “PHP-MySQL” or something similar.
>
> There are currently two interfaces PHP provides as MySQL extensions - mysql >and mysqli. The mysqli is tried first, because it’s the best one.

Also I have already tried to modify the php.ini file adding or uncommenting these following lines:

```
extension=mysqli
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysqli.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and then tried to reinstall the phpmyadmin with and without configuring a database by dbconfig-common. also reinstalled mysql-server (version 5.7.24) with and without secure_installation.

With apache2 i've installed the following php packages:

```
php php-cgi libapache2-mod-php php-common php-pear php-mbstring
```

With nginx i've installed the following php packages:

```
php-fpm php-mysql
```

but none of this even changed the error message (even after purging packages and manually removing folders and reinstalling).

Important to note that all the programs in stack works fine. making me think that is some issue with phpmyadmin.

So, I wanted enter to the login screen of phpmyadmin, but nothing seems to work. already tried several solutions, several times. if someone could help me with this, please answer! thanks.

Comment: Which exact php.ini did you edit? Which service did you restart afterwards? What's in the error.logs? Is it Apache or Nginx now? And which PHP SAPI is used with either? What were your observations with `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Restart the web server once you have installed the extension.
Also, hoping you have only one installation of php. Could you share the output of the following command - `php -m | grep mysql`

Comment: @mario actually in nginx, I`ve edited the php.ini from '/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini' like is showing in phpinfo(); Sorry but i dont know exactly if im using another SAPI. Just installed clean LEMP + phpmyadmin yet.

@ValerianPereira here is the output of the command:
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change some configuration and haven't remove it in reinstall, then didn't help. Follow this command to clear old configs:

```
sudo apt purge php7.2-* phpmyadmin
```

After removed, reinstall packages:

```
sudo apt install apache2 php7.2 php7.2-mysql # Add other dependent if you need ...
```

Now, `mysqli` should exists in `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/20-mysqli.ini`:

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqli.ini
; configuration for php mysql module
; priority=20
extension=mysqli.so
```

If you using `FPM`, should have a soft link in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini`

Comment: looks like i haven`t removed it enough. its now working on apache and nginx.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue. Dont worry i have a solution. Go to xampp/php/ext.
then searh for a file php_mysqli.dll if you have this file then go to xampp/php and search for php.ini, php.ini-development, php.ini-production open these three files with your code editor one by one and search for the code look like

```
 =====================
Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; https://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
   ==================
```

change the code with this code

```
=============
Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; https://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
================
```

save the code and problem will be solved.