# Mysqli extension is missing while using the updated version of PHP in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, laragon

I have a problem here that says :

phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

[image: Phpmyadmin proposed solution :]

What i did is I tried to read that, ofcourse and I tried to do some trial and error in the internet and I assumed that this is the PHP-Mysql Software package the error said :

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysqlnd/

Where should I put these files ? in what directory / folder ?

Comment: edit your php.ini and comment out mysqli extention

Comment: I solved this problem, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743224/12004905