# How do i remove the mysqli error on php 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I am facing an error with PHP 7.2:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See [a@doc/html/faq.html#faqmysql@documentation]our documentation for
>   more information.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I got PHP 7.2 and I have in the php.ini file: extension=mysqli.

Comment: Try `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Do you see `mysqli` there?

Comment: Is it `extension=mysqli` enabled, i.e. there is no `#` at the beginning?

Comment: did you reboot your PC ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this question on SO. There are other solution. Try out which works for you.

[The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646655/the-mysqli-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently where I have PHP 7.2 and I have in the php.ini file: extension=mysqli. uncommented and the extension was in the ext/ folder.

The issue was that I had uncommented another line:
Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)

I am not sure why this caused an issue with the mysqli extension, but it did and it took me a long time to debug.  Someone else smarter than me might be able to provide an answer.

Most people will probably solve the issue by making sure the mysqli extension is uncommented in php.ini and available in the ext/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:
Go to the php.ini file, search for "extension=msqli".
Then beneath the above line is a path indicating where the extension is gotten from in your C:\ drive. Now you can either change this to ".so" or ".dll" depending on what you have in your PHP extension folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Sorry if it is too late to help and for my bad english writting : maybe this will work for you if none of the other given solutions did not work  , so try this one :

in your httpd.conf ( apache configuration file ) , find out the line that shows the PHPinitDir , it may looks like this :

`PHPIniDir "C:\Program Files\PHP\\"`

in this line , try to remove the last backslash so that it becomes like this :

`PHPIniDir "C:\Program Files\PHP"`

lastly restart apache server so that it updates this new config ...

Hopes it helps

Thank you and Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Try the below steps. This should solve your problem.

In file php.ini find the link that says **extension=mysqli**.

Replace by: **extension="C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"**.

Restart apache.

Comment: Ubuntu won't have a C:\ drive.

Comment: It was not mentioned that Ubuntu was being used.

Comment: The question was tagged `ubuntu`, and still is.

Answer (score -1):

in my case it fixed by deleting browser cookie!