# PHP 7.4 PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, debian

I was installing PhpMyAdmin and everything was good, mysqli is installed, but for some reason phpmyadmin says:

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

I tried everything, changing the php.ini, reinstalling everything. Nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646655/the-mysqli-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration)

Comment: Sadly not, I was looking at this one 10 Minutes ago, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Baxo you must stop and restart the server after modifying config files

Comment: I'm doing : service apache2 restart

Comment: Please spend a few minutes to install a lower version of phpmyadmin and see the effect. (you may download here https://www.oldapps.com/phpmyadmin.php or other internet sites).

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with sid? You are a brave warrior.
what does your `php -v` say ? Alternative you can use to check it out:

```
apt-cache policy php7.4
```

Does it really say you have 7.4 installed?

Okay if it says 7.4 installed, then install php7.4-mysql

```
apt install php7.4-mysql
```

(note that it depends on libc6 >= 2.15)

if you do not have apt then you can download php7.4-mysql from here:
https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.4-mysql

anyway you'll need all the following packages in the end : php7.4, php7.4-cli, php7.4-curl, php7.4-gd, php7.4-intl, php7.4-json, php7.4-mbstring, php7.4-mysql, php7.4-opcache, php7.4-readline, php7.4-xml, php7.4-xsl, php7.4-zip, php7.4-bz2, libapache2-mod-php7.4

and then after install

```
    cat /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini | grep extension=mysqli
    ;extension=mysqli // uncomment it
    
    cat /etc/php/7.4/cgi/php.ini | grep extension=mysqli
    ;extension=mysqli // uncomment it
    
    cat /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.in | grep extension=mysqli
    ;extension=mysqli // uncomment it
```

in the end reboot your box.

wish you good luck.