# After adding PHP 8 to wamp phpmyadmin is not working

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have added PHP 8 to WAMP by following this [tutorial](https://www.myonlineedu.com/blog/view/16/how-to-update-to-php-8-in-wamp-server-localhost).

After that I found error opening PHPMyAdmin. The error says `phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.`

I Restarted WAMP and all services few times and even restarted my laptop. Made changes to PHP.ini as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122591/9045466) but still not working.

Also this error happened while trying to migrate changes to database from Laravel, I am not sure if this is helpful in analysing the problem.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\pdo_firebird (The specified module could not be found), C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\pdo_firebird (The specified module could not be found), C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on 
line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found), C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0    

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found), C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.3/ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci')

  at D:\Laravel\example-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

  1   D:\Laravel\example-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists")

  2   D:\Laravel\example-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Comment: Are you sure the version of phpmyadmin you're using supports PHP 8? You can check here: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news

Comment: That tutorial is complete nonsense! Assuming you have WAMPServer 3 (and if you dont, then upgrade) all these extra versions of Apache/MySQL/mariaDB/PHP are available on sourceforge (and [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en), much easier to navigate) Just click on the version you want, that downloads an install (that does everything right), run the install, there you go EASY

Comment: Also NEVER add the WAMPServer PHP folder to the Windows PATH