# phpMyAdmin - Error: The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration(with MAMP)

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mamp

I wanted to connect to the database, but an error occurs. In MAMP, everything works correctly: Apache Server and MySQL Server. I am using version 8.0.1 of PHP on Windows 10.

[image]

Actions taken:

1. I uncommented "extension=mysqli" (didn't help)
2. Tried replacing the line with "extension=C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.0.1\php_mysqli.dll" (didn't work)
3. Checked if there is "on" in the line "mysqli.allow_local_infile = on" (didn't help)

Ask for Help!

P.S. I can provide additional photo if necessary.

### Note

I did all the above steps given in the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646655/the-mysqli-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration/52122591#52122591), but it seems to me the main difference is that I use **MAMP** rather than XAMPP nor LAMP.

Comment: did you restart mamp after appying the edit?

Comment: Yes, after each suggested action, I did restart and even tried to reinstall MAMP