# phpmyadmin error: The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: phpmyadmin

I go to Apache24>conf>httpd and change index.html to index.php. After that i refresh Apache in services and to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` and recieve the following error:

phpMyAdmin- Error

The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

```
 <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

Can any one help me understand this error?

Comment: Already answered in below link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617288/phpmyadmin-windows-xampp-missing-mysql-extension-issue

Answer (score 11):

1. Install php5-mysql extension by `apt-get install php5-mysql` command
2. Add `extension=mysqli.so` (near other 'extension=' lines) line to your php.ini
3. Restart apache service by `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` command

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just need clarification: 1) apt-get install php5-mysql, should i put that command in command prompt? 2) i have php.ini-development and php.ini-produtcion, which file should i add extension=myqli.so

Comment: My answer is actual for Debian Linux.
For Windows it will be helpful for you: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)
You need to put php_mysqli.dll to your ext folder and then edit php.ini.

2) php.ini-development and php.ini-produtcion is a EXAMPLE files. Rename php.ini-production to php.ini

Comment: i uncommented extension=mysqli.dll inside php.ini folder and php.ini - production. Then i restarted the service Apache. But still i am recieving the same error and php_mysqli.dll is already there under ext folder

Answer (score 2):

Try visiting phpmyadmin here...

http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/

instead of

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: still the same message

Comment: This works to me, I think there are 2 instance of phpmyadmin installed in the same server.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

1. Try to Uncomment this line in php.ini
2. Restart your apache server

Answer (score 1):

Try to check to check your httpd-xampp config file.

Make sure the Make sure the Php-Module conform with your current php version.

example here: IfModule php5_module

Based on your migration you are using php7, so edit all the php5_module tag in your config file to php7_module and restart the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

## First check you PHP Version From

```
php -v
```

say version is php7.1

### Install mysql from:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

### Then restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, laragon, php8 user, (this is what i did)

1. Make sure Your extension_dir in php.ini points to your *Disk*:/laragon/bin/php/php-*version*/ext (with double quotes)
2. Make sure you have extension named php_mysqli in that (ext) folder
3. Uncomment (line) extension=mysqli by deleting the semicolon(;)
4. Restart laragon

this is enough for me, hope it helps you.