# Windows XAMPP Missing MySQL Extension

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have read this question and it didn't help me:

[PHPMyAdmin Windows XAMPP Missing MySQL Extension Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617288/phpmyadmin-windows-xampp-missing-mysql-extension-issue)

Tomorrow I have a big demonstration where I demonstrate my project (for my internship) and I wanted to install 2different xampp versions because the pc's there are a little funky sometimes and better be safe than sorry. But now whenever I start xampp and go to PHPMyAdmin it gives me an error

> missing php mysqli extension

I tried everything in the question linked above but nothing works.

I restarted my pc, delete all xampp versions on my pc but still nothing.

Tried installing on a different pc, worked plugged the USB drive back into my pc and it still works. Though this is not a solution since I still can't install a xampp version even if I delete the current version on my usb or try to install it on my pc (without USB).

Comment: Which XAMPP version?

Comment: 7.4.7 (lowest button of the 3 in the download page for windows)

Comment: I am very skeptical of running two XAMPP installations on the same machine, this sounds like a recipe for disaster, conflicting applications trying to claim ports (80, 3306, etc), and possibly data corruption if both database programs point to the same MySQL/MariaDB data directory. Since XAMPP should come with all of the pieces needed, working together directly after installation, I have to guess that your error message relates to some conflict with shared resources or other conflict from running the two versions at the same time.

Comment: I'm curious which `php.ini` was shown in the output of phpinfo() as your configuration file, and whether the extension line was already commented out when you edited it. Did the MySQL extension show in the `phpinfo()` output? Anyway, I think we should move on from the old error about a missing mysql extension, because you've now removed both XAMPP installations since then and you say you're getting a different problem now that we can address. You said you can't install any XAMPP now. What is the cause or symptom of that problem? Does the installer give an error message?

Comment: I can install xampp but I will still get the same error when i install it on the same pc, but when i install on a different pc it works and is able to run on the pc where it cant be installed.

Comment: Simce you were curious if the line was commented out, it wasn't